# Building custom magento payment extension - ./mage install-file … - exception thrown - Package file is invalid ‘. …’ file already exists

Tags: magento, payment, custom-attributes

I’ve created payment module which requires that billing address have date of birth and gender attributes. One of the things was a change in:
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

I added new fields for adding date of birth and gender attributes,

After this I built package extension in Magento 1.5.0.1 and then I wanted to verify extension installation in clean Magento deployment. For this I used mage command line tool. I did:

mage install-file My_Extension-0.1.0.tgz.

This command line reports:

install-file: Package file is invalid
‘./app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml’ already exists

The questions are:

- did I make mistake by changing this template file? Would it be better that I override it?
- is there some undocumented option in mage command line tool that should be used - like “mage install-file My_Extension-0.1.0.tgz force” or something similar that will ignore this exception?
- is this proper procedure for veryfing extension?
- are there any guidelines what is best way to test magento extension deployment - before releasing it to Magento Connect?

Thanks for your time.
Damir

Answer (score 0):

- yes never modify default templates
- no , only chuck norrys has the Magento documentation
- no
- yes and you can find them on magento website

Comment: **Thanks**. What will be the proper procedure for verifying extension?

Comment: Chuck Norris needs no Magento documentation, he can _feel_ the core.

Comment: What does it mean "verifying"? When you upload package to magento connect - you package structure is verified. What else do you need? And as Anton said, **never modify magento files**.